# How can I make Spring Data MongoDB sort Java Sets when saving as arrays?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a [Spring Data MongoDB](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb) type containing a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) types ([`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) in my specific case).  This is logically a set, an it is therefore represented as such in the object.  Spring Data MongoDB saves the set to the database as a MongoDB array.

```java
public class MyType {
    private Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek;

    public Set<DayOfWeek> getDaysOfWeek() { return daysOfWeek; }
    public void setDaysOfWeek(Set<DayOfWeek> d) { this.daysOfWeek = d; }
}
```

An array in MongoDB is an ordered data structure, but Java's `Set` is not.  Therefore, when the `Set` is translated to the MongoDB type by Spring, an ordering is by necessity applied to the elements.  The resulting array is in the `Set`'s (generally arbitrary) iteration order, and not in a logical sorted order (or even in a guaranteed consistent order).

Using an arbitrary, inconsistent iteration order causes a number of (minor) issues.  It makes the data more annoying to work with: it's harder to see what elements are present at a visual glance, and any tests on the database structure itself need to make sure they're ignoring the ordering of the resulting MongoDB array.  It also means that the MongoDB field value could change over time despite it logically being the same value (and being the same value in the Java model), since the iteration order could vary each time the object is saved.  Depending on how differences are determined, it could result in unnecessary updates to the database, since the array ordering may have changed even though nothing of any import has actually changed.

What I would like is the ability to use the natural order of the `Set` elements when saving the object to a MongoDB document.  Ideally, I do not want to force the Java type to be a sorted set, since there is no logical reason it needs to be one, beyond wanting them saved in a predictable sorted order for convenience and consistency.

How can I ensure that my object containing an unordered `Set` is saved to MongoDB in a sorted order?

Answer (score 2):

A `Set` by definition does not have an iteration order. The name “set” was chosen from [the mathematical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) meaning a collection of distinct unordered elements.

If you need the elements to iterate in a certain order, use an implementation of `SortedSet` or its successor `NavigableSet`.

Note that you can use a sorted set internally within your class while using the more general `Set` interface when interacting with the world outside your class. For your setter method, accept a `Set` object, then feed that to a constructor of your chosen `NavigableSet` such as `TreeSet`. For your getter method, return a defensive copy of your internal `NavigableSet` as a `Set`.

Your case is special in that you are working with enum `DayOfWeek`. If you want those sorted in the order defined by ISO 8601, Monday-Sunday, use an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) as your internal set object. While not a `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet`, the `EnumSet` class promises to maintain an iteration order per the order in which the enum objects are declared.

```java
public class MyType {
    private EnumSet< DayOfWeek > dows ;

    public Set< DayOfWeek > getDaysOfWeek() { return EnumSet.copyOf( this.dows) ; }
    public void setDaysOfWeek( Set< DayOfWeek > d ) { this. dows = EnumSet.copyOf( d ) ; }
}
```

You said:

> since there is no logical reason it needs to be one, beyond wanting them saved in a sorted order for convenience.

Actually, wanting them saved in sorted order is indeed a logical reason the specify a `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet`. I would recommend exporting the sorted variety of set rather than `Set`. I wrote my Answer to use `Set` only because you asked for it.

Comment: I think it's inaccurate to say that "A set by definition does not have an iteration order."  Per [`Set.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#iterator()), "The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee)."  So sets are allowed to have defined iteration orders, which _some_ sets do, including `SortedSet`, `EnumSet`, and `LinkedHashSet`.  It is fair to say that the `Set` interface imposes no iteration order on classes implementing it, however.

Comment: @M.Justin I’ll stand by my wording. When you encounter a `Set` you cannot expect a sorted order. The fact that a `Set` may happen to exhibit a sorted order is meaningless. You cannot reasonably depend on that apparent order. Why? Because the Javadoc says so. Indeed, in recent versions of OpenJDK, the behavior of the set returned by `Set.of` methods was altered so that now the elements are iterated in a newly randomized order *on each iteration* to dissuade programmers from relying on an apparent order. If you promise a sorted set, use `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet`, that is their purpose.

Comment: I think we are in full agreement on API behavior but in slight disagreement on sentence semantics in describing said behavior. ‍♂️

Comment: @M.Justin If that sentence meant you could expect sorted behavior from a `Set`, then the  `SortedSet` interface would never have been written.

Comment: Sorry, I meant our your and my own description of API behavior, not the Java API description of the behavior.  I guess my point is that the `Set` interface doesn't disallow having a well-defined iteration order, and leaves that decision up to its subclasses.  Saying it "by definition does not have an iteration order" to me reads as being counter to the possibility of subclasses defining an order.  That said, this is such a tangential point, and approaching the boundaries of what's appropriate for SO comments vs. chat, that I think it's fair to say we disagree on phrasing and leave it at that.

Comment: @M.Justin Not to beat a dead horse, but the point you are missing is that *from the perspective of a `Set`* there is no iteration order. While an underlying concrete class like `TreeSet` and `EnumSet` can promise an iteration order, when an object of those classes is presented *as a `Set`* their ordered iteration becomes (a) only an irrelevant implementation detail, and (b) only an *apparent* ordering that cannot be relied upon, as emphasized by the revised behavior of `Set.of` sets that now randomly change their ordering on each iteration.

Comment: @M.Justin I believe this comment thread is quite helpful, important, worthwhile, and on-topic. This issue has obviously confused enough programmers who are mistakenly relying on a `Set` object’s apparent ordering that the Java team felt the need to change the behavior of the `Set.of` methods’ returned objects to now be randomized. So thanks for your calm clear elucidation of your points. I’m sure this will help others.

Comment: We hit the "extended discussions" warning, so I'll avoid further comments on that topic outside of chat. To instead address the point of my question: if this were a non-declarative ORM I had manually written, I would order the set elements immediately prior to converting it to the MongoDB array type. I have it as an unordered `Set` since from a conceptual data modeling standpoint, it's unsorted.  It's also a (slight) pain in the application tier to use an ordered `Set` type, when for the most part I don't care about its type.  Wondering if there's a way to do the same in Spring Data.

Comment: Java 21 is introducing the [`SequencedSet`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) interface, which is the interface for a `Set` that also has a well-defined encounter order (such as `SortedSet` & `LinkedHashSet`).